# how to shuffle a list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am adding shuffle() function but the error is showing Another exception was thrown: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' is there any solution to put question in shuffle i don't know where to add this shuffle function there was not any error in this project the json files is added with this code
i am adding mydata.shuffle() in this code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setasset();
    return FutureBuilder(
      future:
          DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(assettoload, cache: false),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        List? mydata = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
        if (mydata == null) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text(
                "Loading",
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return quizpage(mydata: mydata);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class quizpage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List mydata;

  quizpage({required this.mydata});
  @override
  _quizpageState createState() => _quizpageState();
}

class _quizpageState extends State<quizpage> {
  _quizpageState();

  Color colortoshow = Colors.indigoAccent;
  int marks = 0;
  int i = 1;
  bool disableAnswer = false;
  // extra varibale to iterate
  int timer = 30;
  String showtimer = "30";

  Map<String, Color> btncolor = {
    "a": Colors.indigo.shade900,
    "b": Colors.indigo.shade900,
    "c": Colors.indigo.shade900,
    "d": Colors.indigo.shade900,
  };

  bool canceltimer = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    starttimer();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void setState(fn) {
    if (mounted) {
      super.setState(fn);
    }
  }

  void starttimer() async {
    const onesec = Duration(seconds: 1);
    Timer.periodic(onesec, (Timer t) {
      setState(() {
        if (timer < 1) {
          t.cancel();
          nextquestion();
        } else if (canceltimer == true) {
          t.cancel();
        } else {
          timer = timer - 1;
        }
        showtimer = timer.toString();
      });
    });
  }

  void nextquestion() {
    canceltimer = false;
    timer = 30;
    setState(() {
      if (i < 10) {
        i++;
      } else {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => resultpage(marks: marks),
        ));
      }
      btncolor["a"] = Colors.indigo.shade900;
      btncolor["b"] = Colors.indigo.shade900;
      btncolor["c"] = Colors.indigo.shade900;
      btncolor["d"] = Colors.indigo.shade900;
      disableAnswer = false;
    });
    starttimer();
  }

  void checkanswer(String k) {
    if (widget.mydata[2][i.toString()] == widget.mydata[1][i.toString()][k]) {
      marks = marks + 5;
    } else {}
    setState(() {
      btncolor[k] = colortoshow;
      canceltimer = true;
      disableAnswer = true;
    });
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), nextquestion);
  }

  Widget choicebutton(String k) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 10.0,
        horizontal: 20.0,
      ),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 60,
        width: 400,
        child: OutlinedButton(
          onPressed: () => checkanswer(k),
          child: Text(
            widget.mydata[1][i.toString()][k] ?? "",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontFamily: "Alike",
              fontSize: 18.0,
            ),
            maxLines: 1,
          ),
          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
              side: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.indigo.shade900),
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              shape: const StadiumBorder()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.portraitDown, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        return await showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                  title: Text(
                    "Quizstar",
                  ),
                  content: Text("You Can't Go Back At This Stage."),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Ok',
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ));
      },
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                  width: 500,
                  height: 200,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage(
                        "assets/canva4.png",
                      ),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  child: Text(
                    widget.mydata[0][i.toString()],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontFamily: "Quando",
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Divider(height: 10, color: Colors.black, thickness: 10),
              Expanded(
                flex: 6,
                child: AbsorbPointer(
                  absorbing: disableAnswer,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        choicebutton('a'),
                        choicebutton('b'),
                        choicebutton('c'),
                        choicebutton('d'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      showtimer,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 35.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontFamily: 'Times New Roman',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you print('data = ${snapshot.data}') before decode it and show me the result?